# Paypal Standard Payment Method - Shopping Cart

Tags: paypal

Sorry I am new. I was trying Paypal Shopping Cart function and i realize that in paypal sandbox cart it allows users to edit the quantity. How do i go about keeping track of these quantity, lets say in my website they keyed 2 for quantity but in the paypal shopping cart they changed it to 1.

Does it mean that it is not recommended to have own shopping cart and orders should be viewed at paypal website?

Many thanks!

Doomie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [cart upload](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/). Then you can upload a list of multiple items the customer selected on your site and customers won't be able to change the quantity after reaching PayPal.